# In vscode using Python, ctrl+F5 always asks for "select environment"

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I installed VSCode, downloaded official Python 3.6.4.

VSCode detected and set the environment right - I do see "python.pythonPath" user setting set correctly.

But, when using VS Code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>to run a Python file, I am always getting asked for "select environment" and it shows me two options
 - Python
 - Python Experimental

What is this "Python Experimental"? How can I get rid of getting interrupted every time I try to run a script?

Comment: Have you read this? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: I did - but newbie here - so pardon me if I am making any rookie mistake. Ctrl + shift + P is showing just the Python 3.6.4 that I have installed on my machine. Also in user settings, I see the path set properly - doc doesn't mention about any "Python Experimental".

Comment: @creimers please stop suggesting edits where you **replace** the Python tag with the version specific tag. You can simply **add** the version specific tag keeping the Python tag.

Comment: @creimers, if by chance you disagree with me, please have a look at this [post on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265845/7832176).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`Run > Add Configuration...` => Choose one of the two options.

After doing this it will no longer prompt you.

Comment: Where are these menus? Choose what options? You can probably sense my frustration ...

Comment: OK, so you mean Run > Add Configuration? What options? Oh never mind, it's just asked me to install node. Honestly Code is such rubbish. All this to run a file when I press F5?

Comment: The menus must have changed - thanks for the update / edit.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is a shortcut to `Start without Debugging` What you want is just running a file according to your post. To run a python file in the integrated terminal, right-click your editor window and `Run Python File in Terminal`. It should open up a terminal window within VS Code and run as normal. It also takes into account the environment you are currently using whenever you run it.

To answer your other question about `Python Experimental`, it is an option to use the experimental debugger, an alternate version of a Python Debugger. You can read the instructions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/538)

Comment: Two follow up questions chaNcharge (1) Is there any way to add a keyboard shortcut to automate the step of right click + pick "run python File in Terminal" (2) How to get rid of the experimental debugger?

Comment: @Azz (1) Go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts. (Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts on Mac), search for `Run Python File in Terminal`, and input your desired keybinding. (2) You can't, it's a debugger built into the python extension and VS Code