# How to preselect (set default) python interpreter in python visual code extension?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The small problem is, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, I want the code to be run immediately; but I have to

```
Select environment:

Python
Python Exprimental
```

all the time. Is there a way to set default env in settings so I don't have to choose at each run?

Comment: user1422543's answer is correct.  Visual Code remembers the settings for a project/workspace using the .vscode/settings.json file which is in the root folder of the project.  Once it is set, every time you open that project, vscode will set the right environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In vscode using Python, ctrl+F5 always asks for "select environment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312540/in-vscode-using-python-ctrlf5-always-asks-for-select-environment)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

vscode deprecated the *python.pythonPath* setting.

Since the [2021.6.0 (16 June 2021) update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#202160-16-june-2021) we should use

Windows:

```
{
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "c:/dev/ala/venv/Scripts/python.exe"
}
```

macOS/Linux:

```
{
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/home/abc/dev/ala/venv/bin/python"
}
```

The vscode documentation has already been updated. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Answer (score 8):

Once you selected an interpreter, it should be stored in the settings.json file in .vscode folder. It should be something like this:

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python.exe"
}
```

Next time you use vscode to open this folder, the python interpreter you used last time should be automatically selected.

Maybe you didn't use "Open folder" to open the working directory. And then vscode will try to read the local .vscode folder if any, otherwise it will follow a certain path order to select an interpreter. Hope that helps.

Comment: NOTE: this solution is deprecated, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68467958/230468

Answer (score 5):

File > Preferences > Settings > User tab > Extensions > python > Python Path

type your python path e.g.: `c:\python35\python.exe`

Comment: Should be using the Python extension default interpreter configuration (using something like `pipenv`) https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

Answer (score 0):

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to launch command pallete and

type python interpreter and you will get an option select interpreter

then select python interpreter

> Choosing an [environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface) By default, the Python extension relies on the
>   first Python interpreter it finds in the path, but it's easy to switch
>   between environments.
>
> To use a specific interpreter, select the Python: Select Interpreter
>   command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).

Comment: This does not help. I select the only one (python 2.7.14 64 bit interpreter), but when I press ctrl+f5 I get the choice between python and python experimental again.

Comment: then press ctrl+, open the setting and search for python, you wil get the option for setting the python interpreter where u give the full path