# How to set default python interpreter in visual code on remote server?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to set default python interpreter-path to avoid being asked every time I log into remote-server.

[image: popup window in vscode]

I tried the method in [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817786/how-to-preselect-set-default-python-interpreter-in-python-visual-code-extensio). My workspace.json now looks like:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "uri": "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+172.1.1.1/home/user/workspace/folder1"
        },
        {
            "uri": "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+172.1.1.1/home/wzy/workspace/folder2"
        }
    ],
    "remoteAuthority": "ssh-remote+172.1.1.1",
    "settings": {
        "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/py38/bin/python",
    }
}
```

But every time I reconnect to the server, I need to manully select the python-interpreter ( otherwise a base `/user/bin/python3` interpreter would be choosen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me!

1. Install [Python Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) on your SSH remote machine(not your local PC!)
2. Open the action bar (F1) and Search for "Python: Select interpreter". You can set it there.

Answer (score 1):

Open the action bar (F1) and select "Open Remote Settings". Search for "default python interpreter". You can set it there.